# Vue dynamic route prerender

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, vue-router, dynamic-routing

I'm working on a Vue project and I've got an issue. 

I would like to prerender some dynamic routes when I am in a particular route.
In my project, I have a `/works` route which displays a list of several items. Each item
has a router-link that sends to his `/work/workID` route and renders the workpage component. As this is a dynamic route, Vue does not prerender these routes and each time I load, I have a 500ms delay of images loaded. 

My images url are store in Vuex and the images are upload in a public google drive folder.


I think that I should use something like that :

```
let matched = router.resolve(work/workID).resolved.matched;
let route = matched[matched.length -1];
route.components.default.render;
```

But my images are still loading on mounted.
Hope someone know the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to resolve it.
I declare my dynamic route props to true, then render and hide all the dynamic components in my works pages. That work perfectly.

I can't find the way to pass route params or even props to a component with the router.resolve(path) method. Someone would know how to do ?